# Handlers in GAE

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I want to ask,i tried to call `webapp.RequestHandler`,but this handler didn't called:
this is compress.py page:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.api import files
import cgi, cgitb ; cgitb.enable()
import StringIO
import zipfile
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
class zip(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def z(self):
        form = cgi.FieldStorage()
        zipstream=StringIO.StringIO()
        zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(file=zipstream,mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)     
        file_upload = form['file[]']
        data=file_upload.file.read()
        filename2 = file_upload.filename
        zfile.writestr(filename2,data)
        zfile.close()
        zipstream.seek(0)
        zip_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/zip',_blobinfo_uploaded_filename='test.zip')
        with files.open(zip_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(zipstream.getvalue())
        files.finalize(zip_file)
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(zip_file)        
        self.response.out.write('<a href="download.py?key=%s">get zip</a>' %blob_key)

def main():
     application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [(r'/compress.py', zip)], debug=True)
     run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

app.yaml:

```
application: my application
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: (.*)/
  static_files: static\1/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
- url: /compress.py
  script: compress.py
- url: /download.py
  script: download.py
- url: /decompress.py
  script: decompress.py
```

Project structure:

```
/index.html
/compress.py
/download.py
```

EDIT:
download.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import urllib
from mimetypes import guess_type

def mime_type(filename):
    return guess_type(filename)[0]

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):
        print "Doaa"
        blob_key = self.request.get('key')
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
        content_type1 =mime_type(blob_info.filename)
        save_as1 =  blob_info.filename
        self.send_blob(blob_info,content_type=content_type1,save_as=save_as1)



def main():

    #application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/',ServeHandler),], debug=True)
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
            (r'/download.*', ServeHandler),
        ], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in this page now when i uploaded my application i get this output at this page(i believe that that this page-download.py-get the blob that has the specfic key in URL and download this file to my PC),but the result as:

```
Status: 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache X-AppEngine-BlobKey: AMIfv96uuwRiM-nYO7sp7nPk5Ny0IDv1mrVCkBhFMPn9AUea4rRg5x8sVWlLFJNQ2PxSKD2s6VNVjiPPZFDyP33EegP_QzLYQEnHdSSj_qindkuqeWB7YYnSeReBDYWDAAOf566LCSyWrXBUPq0Z_NiGtZjyvM3-5exv3TxIOYc9PBYuTQ3Vpww Content-Type: application/zip Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip" Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Content-Length: 0
```

without saving?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 for code screenshot. Seriously?

Comment: @Adam Crossland:Why, i put my code at another question (not as screenshot)but the problem is still.

Comment: For the reasons outlined by Nick in his answer.

Comment: @Adam Crossland:I edited my question have any suggestions about this problem?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman:I edited my question now??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're posting to `/compress.py`, replace

```
def z(self):
```

with

```
def post(self):
```

That'll get you to your next problem.

As an aside, you'll probably find it easier to take smaller steps. A small step in this case would be "can I hit a handler via URL and at least get a 'hello world' result?". Maybe you've already done that. The next small step is "Can I post to a handler and get a 'hello world' result?" Doing that without worrying at all (yet) about what to do with posted data removes a lot of possible problems from consideration. Take those problems on small step by small step.

Comment: :Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you're going to be playing with blobs, a very handy handler to have is one that shows all of your BlobInfo entities, including key, mime type, and size. I think you'll find that you've managed to store a zero-length blob.

Comment: @ Dave W. Smith:but when i check the blobstore of my application the files is stored successfully??

Answer (score 6):

Don't use print statements within a WSGI app - and do use WSGI. You need to follow one of the App Engine tutorials such as [this one](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/), write a proper WSGI app, put all your code inside handlers (or called from handlers), and use `self.response.out.write` instead of print statements.

You also need to stop asking nearly identical questions until you've got a good handle on how to write a basic webapp.

Comment: :i tried as you said,define class zip as :class zip(webapp.RequestHandler):,and in the main i call it as:run_wsgi_app( webapp.WSGIApplication( [('/', zip),], debug=True)),but nothing is executed now??